# 2x2 Matrix Inverse Question

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $a, b, c, d\in \mathbb{R}$. I'm asked to determine the products of the ($2x2$) matrices

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a&b\\
c&d\\
\end{bmatrix} and
\begin{bmatrix}
d&-b\\
-c&a\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and show that the first matrix is invertible if and only if $ad \neq bc$.

Calculating the product is pretty straightforward:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a&b\\
c&d\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
d&-b\\
-c&a\\
\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}
ad-bc&-ab+ba\\
cd-dc&-bc+ad\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

And I know that a matrix A is invertible if I can find a matrix B such that $AB=I$ or $BA = I$. Any hints on how to show that the first matrix is invertible if and only if $ad \neq bc$?

Comment: A sq matrix is invertible iff its determinant is non-zero.

Comment: Note:  $cd-dc=-ab+ba=0$ for $a,b,c,d\in\Bbb R$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your step we have

$$\begin{bmatrix}
ad-bc&-ab+ba\\
cd-dc&-bc+ad\\
\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}
ad-bc&0\\
0&ad-bc\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

and we need $ad-bc\ne 0$.

Notably form here we can see that

$$\begin{bmatrix}
a&b\\
c&d\\
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}=\frac1{ad-bc}\begin{bmatrix}
d&-b\\
-c&a\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: What's the formula you used to get $\frac{1}{ad-bc}$ (the fraction)?

Comment: @Cesare You have already show that the product of the matrices is a diagonal matrix. If we divide this diagonal matrix by $ad-bc\neq 0$ we obtain the identity matrix. Therefore the matrix I've indicated is the inverse of $ \begin{bmatrix}
a&b\\
c&d\\
\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Thank you. So $ad-bc\neq0$ because the denominator can't be $0$, correct?

Comment: @Cesare Yes exactly, and also because we want to obtain the identity matrix at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You're just there:

Denote the two matrices by $A$ and $B$. Then we have
$$AB=(ad-bc)I$$
Hence, $A\cdot \frac1{ad-bc}B=I$ whenever $ad-bc\ne0$.

Answer (score 0):

A linear map $A:\mathbb R^2\rightarrow \mathbb R^2$ is invertible if it is one-one. For one-one it is sufficient to show that $ker(A)=$ {$0$} which is equivalent to state that $A$ has full rank$\implies det(A)\ne 0\implies ad-bc\ne 0$

Answer (score -1):

You can use the fact that a square matrix is invertible if and only if it has a non-zero determinant. If ad = bc then it is easy to show matrix A will have determinant 0.